# Знаки препинания при обобщающем слове

Tags: пунктуация, сказуемые, подлежащее

Добрый день. В научной литературе встречается разнобой в поставке знаков препинания в предложениях типа: "Показатели качества закваски: влажность (–) 74–75 %, кислотность конечная (–) 10–14 град, подъёмная сила (–) от 20-30 мин". Как все-таки должно быть? Если "показатели" - это обобщающее слово, то "влажность", "кислотность" и "сила" - это однородные, а цифры - это определения. Или все-таки "влажность - 74-75 %" - это подлежащее и сказуемое  и тире ставится по соответствующему правилу, но тогда как быть с обобщающим словом?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Тире здесь опционально, это факт, можно считать, что вместо опущенного сказуемого (оно там не строго обязательно в подобных конструкциях), а можно и совсем по-другому грамматику понимать, родовое слово + значение,: наподобие "Улица Имерекова, дом 17" - тут-то тире не нужно?! Но причем тут обобщающее слово и прочие ваши рассуждения?!

Comment: behemothus, спасибо за ответ. Уточняю вопрос. Могут ли при наличии обобщающего слова после двоеточия идти грамматические основы? Ведь если ставить тире, то получается, что "влажность" - подлежащее в именительном падеже, 74 % - сказуемое-числительное. И еще. Я правильно поняла, что, согласно Вашему примеру, необходимо после родового слова ставить запятую: влажность, 74 %?

Comment: @Стася Понятно. Вернее непонятно. А почему нет-то?! Хоть целыми предложениями: *Данный принцип распространяется на следующие случаи: Петя любит Машу, Даша любит Сашу, Мойша любит покушать цимес*. Или я опять Вас не так понимаю?

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо! Все доступно и понятно! Просто раньше не встречала такие случаи, вот и возник вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем понятен. Тире здесь опционально, это факт, можно считать, что вместо опущенного сказуемого (оно там не строго обязательно в подобных конструкциях), а можно и совсем по-другому грамматику понимать, родовое слово + значение,: наподобие "Улица Имерекова, дом 17" - тут-то тире не нужно?! Но причем тут обобщающее слово и прочие ваши рассуждения?! –

> *behemothus, спасибо за ответ. Уточняю вопрос. Могут ли при наличии обобщающего слова после двоеточия идти грамматические основы? Ведь
>   если ставить тире, то получается, что "влажность" - подлежащее в
>   именительном падеже, 74 % - сказуемое-числительное. И еще. Я правильно
>   поняла, что, согласно Вашему примеру, необходимо после родового слова
>   ставить запятую: влажность, 74 %? – Cтася 3 часа назад*

@Стася Понятно. Вернее непонятно. А почему нет-то?! Хоть целыми предложениями: *Данный принцип распространяется на следующие случаи: Петя любит Машу, Даша любит Сашу, Мойша любит покушать цимес. Или я опять Вас не так понимаю*?

*Вот запятую там ставить не надо, это Вы не так меня поняли*. Запятая только между элементами списка. Аналогия была "Дом 17" и "Влажность 17%". В обычном тексте я бы предпочел без знака, в научном (с длинным списком составляющих) - с тире, но и то больше для наглядности. Если вопрос принципиальный, то тут нужен опытный технический редактор, там наверняка есть тонкости.

Answer (score 0):

Надо ставить тире, так как между существительного и цифры можно поставить глагол: влажность равна 74-75%, подъёмная сила длится от 20-30 минут.